# will the PC boot from the DVD and install Ubuntu on an empty hard disk?

Tags: system-installation

I have an extra PC and its hard drive died. I would like to buy a new hard drive, 500gig, and load Ubuntu. My question though is if I burn Ubuntu iso with an ISO Burner, will the PC boot from the DVD and install Ubuntu on an empty hard disk?

Answer (score 2):

Yes, it will. You just need to set your BIOS for boot from DVD after installing your HD. Follow the instructions on the installation wizard and that's it.

Answer (score 1):

There are several considerations. If you never have run Ubuntu on the target system then you could know just by using the Live CD/USB and verifying everything is working. If you have already installed Ubuntu, the new hard drive do not change anything of importance to Ubuntu and everything might work the same as when you installed the system. So, will Ubuntu boot up on your system? The only answer is just test it.